# How To Change All "Buy" Button Urls To The One

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an affiliate site with about 800 products, my existing affiliate is dead and I want to redirect all the traffic to another.

The easiest was I see now is to change all "BUY" button urls with the new affiliate link (to the homepage of my new affiliate program).

So, I need a solution to do this, does someone know the answer? thanks

Comment: what is your affiliate button function

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the url via the `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url` filter in the [`add_to_cart_url()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-external.php#L47-49) method of the product class.

```
function so_30862586_add_to_cart_url( $url, $_product ) {
    if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        $url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'so_30862586_add_to_cart_url', 10, 2 );
```